# How to dynamically call overloaded methods inside .handle() with two arguments in spring integration?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I want to make my spring integration flow generic for different type of requests that is coming through gateway and I want to have overloaded methods and want to call specific overloaded method for specific messaged that is coming though gateway.

```
flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
```

Something like the above code, where inside validatorService I have several overloaded methods to cater different requests that are coming to this flow. But what if along with the payload I want to send another argument to a method. Then how do I do that.

```
@Configuration
        public class IntegrationConfiguration {
          @Autowired LionsServiceImpl lionsService;
        
          long dbId = new SequenceGenerator().nextId();
      //   Main flow
      @Bean
  public IntegrationFlow flow() {
    return flow ->
        flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")
            .split()
            .channel(c -> c.executor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool()))
            .scatterGather(
                scatterer ->
                    scatterer
                        .applySequence(true)
                        .recipientFlow(flow1())
                        .recipientFlow(flow2())
                        .recipientFlow(flow3()),
                gatherer ->
                    gatherer
                        .releaseLockBeforeSend(true)
                        .releaseStrategy(group -> group.size() == 2))
            .aggregate(prepareSomeRequest())
            .to(getDec());
  }
```

//gateway

```
 @Gateway(requestChannel = "flow.input")
  void processLionRequest(
      @Payload Message lionRequest, @Header("sourceSystem") SourceSystem sourceSystem);
```

So if u see in  `flow.handle(validatorService, "validateRequest")` we have a validatorService class which accepts LionRequest, CatRequest and dynamically calls the overloaded method.
Same way I have overloaded method which accepts 2 argument, one is either LionRequest or CatRequest and another value from header or from some variable.

My overloaded methods looks like below -

```
public LionRequest save(LionRequest lionreq, String dbID){}

public CatRequest save(CatRequest catReq, String dbID){}..
```

So that to the gateway I can pass LionRequest or CatRequest and I just have to call save method from a class and dynamically LionRequest/CatRequest overloaded method should be called.

Kindly suggest. One example code would help

Answer (score 0):

We need to understand what is that "another argument", but if you talk just about a `Message` context, than it is possible like this:

```
Foo validateRequest(Foo payload, @Header("fooHeader") String fooHeader)

Bar validateRequest(Bar payload, @Header("barHeader") String barHeader)
```

See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/configuration.html#annotations

The reference from the `handle()` in the flow definition is exactly as you have it now in the question.

Comment: I want to call the overloaded methods dynamically based on the message that's coming from gateway. The arguments to that overloaded methods are payload object and something from header or some variable. In case of one argument we can just call the method as being shown in the .handle(), and it'll automatically pass the payload and dynamically call the suitable overloaded method. I want it to work with two arguments. kindly suggest.

Comment: The method choice can be done only if we deal with a payload type. If you expect the whole `Message<?>` as an input for the method call, then framework cannot do a routing decision. You must implement such a logic yourself in a single top generic method. I said you in one place: the flow must be a generic as possible and hard logic must be delegated to target services.

Comment: No Artem I don't want to pass the whole message. I want  to pass the payload dynamically at the same time one common argument along with that which will come from Header. See my edited question.

Comment: So, why that `@Header("someHeader")` on that `String dbID` param doesn't work for you?